# How do I summon the Golem boss?

Tags: terraria

I am wondering how to summon the Golem boss in Terraria on PC. I have defeated Plantera.

**How do I summon the Golem boss?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have defeated [Plantera](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera), you should have now a [Temple Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Temple_Key) in your inventory (it is a 100% drop from this boss). If you didn't get the key, nor anyone in your group, you must beat Plantera again if you want to proceed.

Now look in the jungle for orange, indestructible bricks. Even your best pickaxe can't mine it (only [the pickaxe looted from the Golem](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Picksaw) can). That is the [Jungle Temple](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle_Temple). Use the Temple Key to get inside through the unique entrance.

At the very end of the temple lies a shiny [Lihzahrd Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Altar) (sometimes, you can even see it shining in the dark from outside the temple). Hold a [Lihzahrd Power cell](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Power_Cell) anywhere in your inventory and right click on the Altar. The Golem has now spawned at the cost of one Power Cell.

[List of Golem drops](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem), some of them are PC-Console only.

Power cells are found in [Lihzahrd Chests](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Chest) (100% chance) and are rare drops from the Temple-specific mobs ([Lihzahrds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_(NPC)) and [Flying Snakes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Flying_Snake)).

If you create a new world and attempt to summon Golem using a Temple Key from another world, he won't spawn. You have to defeat Plantera in the current world in order to face Golem, which means that you can't legitimately summon Golem in a pre-hardmode world (though it is possible using world-editing tools).

Anomaly: Sometimes, in multiplayer, there is a bug that doesn't make the Golem spawnable upon Plantera's defeat.

Answer (score 1):

Golem is summoned by activating the Lihzahrd altar found in the final chamber of the jungle temple. Activation requires one Lihzahrd power cell, which must be present in the player's inventory. The activation automatically consumes one power cell and spawns the golem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Get a lizard power cell in jungle ruins. Unlock the jungle ruins with a temple key from Plantera. A lizard chest inside the jungle ruins always contains one. Find the last room which should have a summoner object. Right click it with the power cell and there you go! Also the golem is very easy to defeat, I would recommend hallowed armour or better.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to beat Plantera on that exact world. You just need a Lihzard Key. Get it by defeating Plantera. Have it in your inventory and click on the jungle door.You need a Lihzard cell to spawn Golem. You can find some in the chests in the Lihzard Temple. Have that in your inventory and click on the Lihzard Altar. The Lihzard Altar is the Thing that has has a glowing yellow thing over it.
    Hope I helped

Comment: The first sentence is wrong on PC : Plantera has to be defeated, or else the golem can't spawn, as for the 1.2.3 version. It's justified by [wiki statement](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem#Notes) and personal experience.